# NumPy: consequences of using 'np.save()' with 'allow_pickle=False'

Tags: python, numpy

According to NumPy documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), by default, a matrix is saved with `allow_pickle=True`, and furthermore, they tell what could be problematic with this default behavior:

> allow_pickle : bool, optional
>   Allow saving object arrays using Python pickles. Reasons for disallowing pickles include security (loading pickled data can execute arbitrary code) and portability (pickled objects may not be loadable on different Python installations, for example if the stored objects require libraries that are not available, and not all pickled data is compatible between Python 2 and Python 3). 
> Default: True

After reading it, I would of course prefer to use `allow_pickle=False` - but they do not tell what is different when it is used this way. There must be some reason they use `allow_pickel=True` by default despite its disadvantages.

Could you please tell whether you use `allow_pickle=False` and how it behaves differently?

Comment: I guess (so not writing an answer) that NumPy uses pickle module for saving non-standard objects, so by disabling it you limit your code to work on standard datatypes.

Comment: Sounds interesting and makes sense. You mean that if I have some class that I save its instances within a NumPy array, then if I disable the usage of `pickle`, it will not be able to save the matrix contents.. right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An object array is just a normal numpy array where the `dtype` is `object`; this happens if the contents of the array aren't of the normal numerical types (like `int` or `float`, etc.).  We can try out saving a numpy array with objects, just to test how this works.  A simple kind of object would be a `dict`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([{x: 1} for x in range(4)])
>>> a
array([{0: 1}, {1: 1}, {2: 1}, {3: 1}], dtype=object)
>>> np.save('test.pkl', a)
```

Loading this back works fine:

```
>>> np.load('test.pkl.npy')
array([{0: 1}, {1: 1}, {2: 1}, {3: 1}], dtype=object)
```

The array can't be saved without using pickle, though:

```
>>> np.save('test.pkl', a, allow_pickle=False)
...
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be saved when allow_pickle=False
```

The rule of thumb for pickles is that you're safe if you're loading a pickle that you made, but you should be careful about loading pickles that you got from somewhere else.  For one thing, if you don't have the same libraries (or library versions) installed that were used to make the pickle, you might not be able to load the pickle (this is what's meant by *portability* above).  *Security* is another potential concern; you can read a bit about how pickles can be abused in [this article](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~s/musings/pickle/), for instance.

Comment: To perhaps clarify (it was not clear to me upon reading) : saving a numpy array of machine ints, floats etc. does not require pickling and numpy will not use pickling regardless of allow_pickle in such a case. Invoking load without disabling pickle still exposes to attacks through deliberately fabricated files.